# How can I make the callback passed into chrome.windows.getAll() asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-chrome-extension

Quick question I hope.  I have been playing around with `chrome.windows.getAll()` which takes in an object and a callback function.  I am getting the data that I need from the method eventually, but I need to run this method asynchronously so that the data comes back before I return what I need from it.  If I log it to the console I see an empty array, but if expanded the data shows up.  I believe this to be the eventual data, but my app will never see it.

I have been using async/await throughout my application without issues, but I feel that I am missing something here.  I can't seem to use what I know to create an asynchronous process.

```
  async function getURLs() {
    let tabs = []

    function getAllOpenWindows(winData) {
      let winTabs = winData[0].tabs

      for (let i = 0; i < winTabs.length; i++) {
        tabs.push(winTabs[i].url)
      }
    }

    try {
      await chrome.windows.getAll({ populate: true }, getAllOpenWindows)

      console.log(tabs)
      return tabs
    } catch (error) {
      return null
    }
  }

  function sessionToState(session) {
    for (let i = 0; i < session.length; i++) {
      dispatch({ type: 'add', value: session[i] })
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form
        method="post"
        onSubmit={async e => {
          e.preventDefault()

          const session = await getURLs()

          sessionToState(session)

          createGroup()
```

In the code snippet above I have tried to use async/await, but I don't believe chrome.windows.getAll is returning a Promise (might not be returning anything?) so it won't work.  I am wondering what approach I should take as I have been stumped for many hours now. If any more of the file or more information from me is needed don't hesitate to ask. Thank you.

Comment: create a Promisified wrapper for `chrome.windows.getAll` :p

Comment: something like `function getAllP = o => new Promise(resolve => chrome.windows.getAll(o, winData => resolve(getAllOpenWindows(winData))));` then you can `await getAllP({ populate: true });`

Comment: Normally, as soon as you see a callback controlling program flow, your promise chain is broken.  Await does not automatically convert callbacks to promises.

Comment: Thank you guys for the responses.  I implemented your Promisisified wrapper @JaromandaX, but how can I get the 'tabs' value to be returned by the top-level promise? ```function getAllOpenWindows(winData) {
    let tabs = []
    console.log(winData)
    let winTabs = winData[0].tabs
    console.log(winTabs)
    for (let i = 0; i < winTabs.length; i++) {
      tabs.push(winTabs[i].url)
    }
    console.log(tabs)
  }

  const getURLs = o =>
    new Promise(resolve =>
      chrome.windows.getAll(o, winData => resolve(getAllOpenWindows(winData)))
    )```

Comment: you return `tabs` .... as you already do

Comment: ahhh, thank you, should have caught that I had console.log instead of return

Comment: Simply use Mozilla's WebExtension polyfill.